# remove leading null characters from string in python

Tags: python

I have a string with leading NUL characters I can see them as null when i open it in notepad++ else its shows as empty space, but any of the strip functions on string doesnot work how can I remove it?

```
exp=
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      {"asctime": "2021-09-07 18:58:37,645", "name": "Frontend_Tableau", "levelname": "DEBUG", "message": "Extracted Dashboard details from tableau", "type": "dashboard", "Name": "Overview"}
```

this is what i have tried

```
exp.lstrip()
```

Comment: What if you do `exp = exp.decode('utf-8').lstrip('\x00').encode('utf-8')`. Also, don't forget that lstrip is not modifying the value in-place, so you have to reassign it (like `exp = exp.lstrip`)

Comment: `exp.lstrip()`
This is actually working.

`>>>

>>> exp = "           Manjesh"

>>> exp

'           Manjesh'

>>> exp.lstrip()

'Manjesh'`


Tested on Python 3.9 Terminal and works great

Comment: @jkoestinger exp is a string type so decode is not supported can I try ***exp=exp.lstrip('\x00')*** is it correct?

Comment: I mixed up `encode` and `decode`, they should be inverted, but manjesh23 seems to have tried directly

Comment: @jkoestinger encode and decode not working for str obj

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`encode` and `decode` should definitely work, I did the same tests as manjesh23:

```py
>>> int(0).to_bytes(1, 'big')  # Creating a null byte (I don't know how yours is created in the first place)
b'\x00'

>>> test = int(0).to_bytes(1, 'big').decode('utf-8') + 'hello'  # Storing it as a string

>>> test
'\x00hello'

>>> print(test)
hello

>>> test.lstrip('\x00')
'hello'

>>> print(test.lstrip('\x00'))
hello
```

If it still doesn't work, we're missing some extra information I think